# Container encerra imediatamente no docker-compose

Tags: docker

Configurei um projeto laravel, criei um docker-compose abaixo:

```
# v3 syntax
version: 3
services:
  # PHP (apache)
  blog:
    image: php:7.1-apache
    container_name: blog-apache
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/blog
      - ./apache/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    command: "chown www-data:www-data /var/www/blog/storage:
```

Porém quando executo o docker-compose up -d no terminal o container da exit, apenas com a linha "command:", quando tiro essa linha o container sobe normal.

Preciso dessa linha command para alterar as permissões na pasta storage. Como posso fazer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim este é o comportamento esperado, porque vc está sobreescrevendo o comando original desta imagem, e o container encerra assim que o seu comando é executado.

Altere seu `command` para o seguinte:

```
command: chown www-data:www-data /var/www/blog/storage && apache2-foreground
```

Comando original desta imagem: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/c856411d1c21111855a54c5d29f2bfe099d63ce7/7.1/stretch/apache/Dockerfile#L258

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta ! porém não funcionou, no log do container foi retornado após eu adicionar: chown: cannot access '&&': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access 'apache2-foreground': No such file or directory

Comment: Tem alguma ideia de como eu posso corrigir ?

Comment: ele deveria estar lá, vc pode tentar adicionar o caminho absoluto (`/usr/local/bin/apache2-foreground`), ou substituir o `&&` por um simples `;`, assim ele inicia mesmo que o `chown` falhe ...

Comment: Agora ele achou o caminho do apache2-foreground, porém não funcionou o "&&" nem o ";" => chown: cannot access '&&': No such file or directory e => chown: cannot access ';': No such file or directory infelizmente :(

Comment: `command: /bin/sh -c 'chown www-data. /var/blog/storage ; apache2-foreground'`

Comment: Funcionou ! Obrigado !!!